# Bit-Operations on a character in ANSI C

Tags: c, bit, unsigned, ansi-c

Can anyone show me a good method to express a character in binary in **C**?
I would need to see a given character as a sequence of 1 and 0.
For example, if I get as an input `'a'`, I would like to see it as 01100001 and finally return **00010110** (a byte with inverted nibbles).
Is it good to use `unigned char`? Should I use an 8-element array of integers to store a byte?

```
int main(void){
   unsigned char c = 'a';

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. With "character", do you mean an ASCII character or does this term include other characters that may use single-byte codes with bit 7 set or multi-byte codes? What exactly do you mean with "I would like to see it as 01100001" do you mean output in binary format (like `printf`) or do you mean conversion to a string? `unsigned char` can be used for operations like bit shifting, masking and combining.

Comment: @Peter Allen - How would you judge which method is _the best method_?

Comment: @Armali "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing more to take away." - Antoine de Saint-Exupéry

Comment: [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format): 57 answers to pick "the best" from, enough to fulfill anyone's personal criteria.

Comment: @usr2564301 No, it is the same proposed by Eraklon. I'm just looking for a type to express a binary variable. I'm not looking for printing.

Comment: Asking for the *best* method is generally frowned upon here, because it involves a lot of opinion. Asking for a *good* method or a method conforming to best pratices would be better. As far as I am concerned, I would never answer a question asking for the best method even I know a good one, because I am pretty sure that it could be improved...

Comment: @SergeBallesta You are right. Just edited.

Comment: @Peter Allen - If you're _not looking for printing_, what do you mean by _I would need to see a given character as a sequence of 1 and 0_? And what do you mean by _a binary variable_, given that most probably every object within your computer is represented in binary bits?

Comment: @Armali I was asking which type should I use to store an input as a variable in order to do operations (such as inverting nibbles) on his bits. Should I use an array of integers?

Comment: Actually a `char` ist just another type of integer.

Comment: There is an answer for every question you present here already on the Stack Overflow.

Comment: `unsigned char` shall be able to represent any character of the basic execution character set and is shift friendly, so it is an appropriate type for bitwise manipulations on characters.

Answer (score 0):

> a byte with inverted nibbles

Since you seem to not care for characters with other than 8 bits, you could do `c = c<<4|c>>4`.

Comment: My question was about the type to use, not about the operation.

Comment: The question about the type has already been answered by Bodo in his comment and the answer incorporated in your post by yourself: `unsigned char`.